# Grandpa has another non math question

Tags: lateral-thinking

Grandpa says, " This is not algebra or may be it is!

IF

> X = 2
>
> R + C = 6
>
> B + P = 5 or 6
>
> Then
>
> What is
>
> I + T ?

There are, with my logic, three different answers!"

Comment: Yay! Another one of these! +1 and favorite.

Comment: Grandpa seems like a troublemaker.

Comment: That he is @Rubio that he is. (Ask Grandma)

Comment: Rot13 (Guerr nafjref, guerr jrveq fcnprf, naq guerr jrveq pncvgnyvmrq yrggref... Uzz... Fb gur nafjre vf 3?)

Comment: not really @Duck But if you know Grandpa he has his weird logic he practices all the time.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but thanks for the [inspiration](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/84871/5373) :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here’s a thought...

X = 2

> X is said like the word “ex” = 2 letters

R + C = 6

> “are” plus “cee” (or “see” or “sea”) = 6

B + P = 5 or 6

> “be” or “bee” plus “pee” (or “pea”) = 5 or 6

Thus, I + T =

> Any of “I”, “ai”, “ay”, “aye” or “eye”, plus “tee” (or “tea”) = 4,5, or 6

for three solutions using the same logic, as requested.

> ... and “ti” would actually allow four answers, 3 4 5 or 6 :)

Comment: heh I thought of this when I saw the puzzle, but Had "R+C" = 5 or 6 and four answers for "I+T", so thought it must be wrong. (rot13 nu)

Comment: I would exclude "ay" from the answers. "ay" is just "aye" the same way "X" is "ex". (unless it means somethings else) but your answer is still valid.

Comment: @Bizhan [ay](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ay) me, you might be right. Er, wait ...

Comment: Oh! ay me! haha!

Answer (score 3):

X = 2

> X is written in two strokes

R + C = 6

> R is 3 strokes and + is 2 stroke, C is 1, combine that will be 6

B + P = 5 or 6

> B is 2 strokes, + is 2, P is 2 which will result in 6?

I + T

> I will be 1 stroke + is 2, T is also 2 which will make 5

Comment: How do you make B two? At least three, surely.

Comment: This was my first thought, but immediately discarded for the reason @Randal'Thor stated.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Rather than print spoilers in the comments - the answer is "the word used is wrong; but the concept is `I` `3`"

Comment: I agree with this one, plus P can be made in 1 stroke, which makes sense for 5 or 6

Comment: This also fails to have 3 possible answers.  You can debate how many there are for `B` or `P`, but `I + T` is pretty unambiguous by these rules.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: I believe that this answer is counting in the ROT13(Oevqtrf bs Xöavtforet) sense.  But, by that interpretation, if you’re willing to ROT13(qenj hcjneqf), B should be 1.  Likewise, P can be 1, and R can be 2 and possibly 1. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … P.S. You say “At least three, surely.” How could it be more than three?

Comment: @PeregrineRook Like [this](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0740/2923/products/letter_B_wall_art_lettering_script_diy_stencils.jpg)?

Comment: @Rubio: Well, OK, but by that standard "I" could be 42.    :-)   ⁠

Comment: @PeregrineRook "At least 42", surely ;)