# A simple association between letters and numbers

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

- $X$ is 5.
- $U$ is 9.
- $O$ is 0 or 7.
- $I$ is 4 or 5 or 7.

What is $V$? And what is $K$ (two options)?

Comment: Inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/84870/5373), but the underlying pattern is *not* the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that

> $V$ is $2$
>  $K$ is $1$ or $3$

Reasoning

> Find the elements in the periodic table whose chemical symbol begins with the letter. The associated numbers are those in the *tens* position of the corresponding atomic numbers.

Examples

> $X \rightarrow$ is Xenon (Xe) whose atomic number is **5**4
>  $U \rightarrow$ Uranium (U) with atomic number **9**2
>  $O \rightarrow$ Oxygen (O) and Osmium (Os) with atomic numbers **0**8 and **7**6
>  $I \rightarrow$ Indium (In), Iodine (I) and Iridium (Ir) with atomic numbers **4**9, **5**3, **7**7
>  $V \rightarrow$ Vanadium (V) with atomic number **2**3
>  $K \rightarrow$ Potassium (K) and Krypton (Kr) with atomic numbers **1**9 and **3**6.
>  **Note:** Oganesson (Og) has not been included here, either it is too new or we are only considering elements less than 100.

Comment: Brilliant! You got it. (I was expecting this one to be solved quicker - just came now to add a hint.)